# $2$-connected graph with minimum degree $d$

Tags: graph-theory

Let $G$ be a $2$-connected graph with minimum degree $d$. Then $G$ contains a cycle of length at least $\min\{2d,|V(G)|\}$.

If $2d$ is at least $|V(G)|$. $\deg(u)+\deg(v) \geqslant |V(G)|$, then $G$  is hamiltonian. 
I am not sure how to prove the second part, if $2d$ is smaller than $|V(G)|$.

Answer (score 1):

The proof I know requires a whole mess of different cases. I'll only show which cases are distinguished, so that some of the exercise remains. :-) We start by choosing a longest path $x_0\cdots x_k$ in $G$. Note that all neighbours of $x_0$ must be among $x_1,\ldots,x_k$, for otherwise the path could be extended. A similar statement holds for the neighbours of $x_k$. Now we distinguish two cases:

1. Suppose there are $j < i$ so that we have edges $x_0x_i$ and $x_kx_j$. Among all possible choices of such $i$ and $j$, choose the pair that minimises the difference $i - j$. Now we consider two subcases:

   - If $i - j = 1$ holds, then we can make a Hamiltonian cycle.
   - If $i - j \geq 2$ holds, then we can make a cycle of length at least $2d$. (Here we really use the minimality assumption on $i - j$.)
2. Otherwise we have two disjoint cycles, one containing all neighbours of $x_0$ and one containing all neighbours of $x_k$. These cycles can be tied together to form a long enough cycle. (Here we use 2-connectedness.)

I think I can produce a reference to a full proof, but first I'll let you try for yourself. :-) Let me know if this works for you. Good luck!